# Oauth auth for Umbraco frontend

Tags: asp.net, oauth, oauth-2.0, umbraco, umbraco7

I need to implement OAuth2 login on my Umbraco website for the frontend part.

I have found a lot of information and tutorials of how to do this on the backoffice part, but none of them describes how to do it in the frontend.

I am gonna use an inhouse Oauth2 authorization server.

I have the following questions right now:

1. I need help writing the template code. Could just be a button saying 'login' but how do I hook it up to the authentication middleware?
2. Our OAuth2 implementation returns a JWT token that contains a users rights. Is it possible to protect views according to the specified rights in the JWT?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I used the AuthU package by @mattbrailsford for this, it works really nicely.

```
PM> Install-Package Our.Umbraco.AuthU
```

There is good documentation on his github page: https://github.com/mattbrailsford/umbraco-authu.

Even if this is not what you want I recommend looking at his code for ideas, he also uses a JWT token: https://github.com/mattbrailsford/umbraco-authu/blob/master/src/Our.Umbraco.AuthU/Services/JwtTokenService.cs

Comment: Hello, im trying to use this package when ever i try to get the token at the path i go for:
/oauth/tokenusername=joebloggs&password=password1234&grant_type=password 

------Always Response with:  
{
    "invalid_grant": "Invalid grant_type"
}

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada do you not need a question mark between token and username, so: /oauth/token?username=joebloggs&password=password1234&grant_type=password

Comment: yes i know its a mistake in the question i have put it but still

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada, sorry I do not know, maybe if you ask a proper question about this, not just in the comments then someone will be more likely to see it who can help.